# null pointer while @Autowried a Service in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using the spring mvc framework
when I use @Autowried to declare a Service in my AbstractPdfView, "commonService" always null pointer.

```
public class DetailPdfView extends AbstractPdfView {


    @Autowired
    private CommonService commonService;


    protected PdfPCell genQRCodeCell(String content){


        String result="";
        try {

            Image img = Image.getInstance(commonService.genQRCode(content));
            img.scaleToFit(120, 120);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img);

            return cell;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        return null;


    }
```

Comment: How are you getting instances of `DetailPdfView`? If you're directly instantiating with `new ...` it instead of getting it from the DI container, the Autowired properties won't be initializied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable annotation-based configuration.

For example, if you are using xml configuration you can include

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

See http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/ for more details.

Also, your bean must be instantiated by Spring, not simply created with e.g. `new DetailPdfView()` for Spring to process the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

is **DetailPdfView** declared as a bean somewhere in your spring configuration?
spring will only process @Autowired if DetailPdfView is declared as a bean in xml onfiguration 
or in your case annotated with one of spring's **stereotype annotations @component, @Service** etc.With component scan enabled as `<context:component-scan base-package="package_to_scan_for_component"/>`